# jQuery - Checking if array is empty or has attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, forms

I'm getting an array of Strings, and if the array has items I want to do one thing and if not I want to do the other. I'm not sure how to check if the array is empty of not. Also when stepping through my code in chrome debugger even if the array has items in it the length is still 0 so I can't use `formErrors.length > 0`.

Here's my code for getting the errors. This works fine and returns an array of error strings or an empty array:

```
var formErrors = validateFormData(formData);

function validateFormData(data) {
    var errors = [];

    if (data["title"].length == 0) {
        errors["title"] = "Project title required";
    }
    if (data["client"].length == 0) {
        errors["client"] = "Client name required";
    }
    if (data["date"].length == 0) {
        errors["date"] = "Date required";
    } else if (!isValidDateFormat(data["date"])) {
        errors["date"] = "Date format invalid - Format: dd/mm/yyyy";
    }
    if (data["status"] == "") {
        errors["status"] = "Please select current status for this project";
    }
    if (data["type"] == "") {
        errors["type"] = "Please select a project type";
    }
    if (data["extras"].length == 0) {
        errors["extras"] = "You must select at least one extra for this project";
    }

    return errors;
}
```

Then I want to do one thing if there's no errors and another if there is. But this is the bit that won't work for me.

```
if (formErrors !== {}) {
        displayFormErrors(formErrors);
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    else {

        clearForm();
    }
```

I've tried multiple ways and nothing has worked so far. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

**EDIT**

I can't use the .length on the array cause the length is 0 even when it has data.

[Screenshot of chrome debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mC9M7.png)

I'm slightly confused about what people are asking sorry, i'm not an expert here is my full code to get a better understanding of what i'm trying to do.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#submit').on("click", onSubmitForm);

function onSubmitForm(event) {
    clearErrorMessages();

    var formData = getFormData();
    var formErrors = validateFormData(formData);

    if (formErrors) {
        displayFormErrors(formErrors);
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    else {

        clearForm();

        // Do other stuff

    }
}

function clearForm() {
    $('#title').val("");
    $('#client').val("");
    $('#date').val("");

    $('#status').val("planning");

    $('#description').val("");

    $('.type').prop('checked', false);
    $('.extra').prop('checked', false);

    $('#title').focus();
}

function clearErrorMessages() {
    $(".uk-text-danger").html("");
}

function getFormData () {
    var data = [];

    data["title"] = $('#title').val();
    data["client"] = $('#client').val();
    data["date"] = $('#date').val();

    data["status"] = $('select#status option:selected').val();

    data["description"] = $('#description').val();

    if ($("input[name='type']:checked").length > 0) {
        data["type"] = $("input[name='type']:checked").val();
    }
    else {
        data["type"] = "";
    }

    data["extras"] = [];
    $.each($("input[name='extras[]']:checked"), function(index, radio) {
        data["extras"].push(radio.value);
    });

    return data;
}

function validateFormData(data) {
    var errors = [];

    if (data["title"].length == 0) {
        errors["title"] = "Project title required";
    }
    if (data["client"].length == 0) {
        errors["client"] = "Client name required";
    }
    if (data["date"].length == 0) {
        errors["date"] = "Date required";
    } else if (!isValidDateFormat(data["date"])) {
        errors["date"] = "Date format invalid - Format: dd/mm/yyyy";
    }
    if (data["status"] == "") {
        errors["status"] = "Please select current status for this project";
    }
    if (data["type"] == "") {
        errors["type"] = "Please select a project type";
    }
    if (data["extras"].length == 0) {
        errors["extras"] = "You must select at least one extra for this project";
    }

    return errors;
}

function displayFormErrors(errors) {
    for (var field in errors) {
        var errorElementId = field + "Error";
        $('#' + errorElementId).html(errors[field]);
    }
} });
```

Sorry if this is too much i'm not sure what else to do.

Comment: just use if(array_name.length == 0){/* do something */}

Comment: You should probably show what your array looks like.

Comment: why do you need the formerrors array? you insert an array inside an array and you check the second array? that does not make sense.. just check errors[] you dont need formErrors

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking, i've added all my code to try and get a better understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var errors = {};` inside the `validateFormData function`.
And then compare the the object like this.

`if (JSON.stringify( formErrors ) !== '{}') { //do something}else { //do something}`

Comment: this seems to have worked but i'm not sure how! thanks anyway :)

Comment: Mistakes what you have done is, you declare the variable errors = [] as array and trying to compare with the object like this if (formErrors !== {}).

Comment: and you cannot compare the object like this eg formErrors !== {} instead you have to convert the object to string using JSON,stringify.

Answer (score 1):

An empty array, string or object is "[falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)" in JavaScript.

That is, you can pass the array, string or object directly into the if conditional and it will run depending on if something is in there or not.

```
if ([]) {
  // this will never run
}
if ('') {
  // this won't run either
}
if ({}) {
  // nor will this
}
```

Comment: Hmmm not exactly.. `var a = []; a.stg = "something", if (a) console.log("yes") // <- yes; a == true; // <- false a == false // <- true a === false // <- false a === true // <- false  a ? true : false // <- true`

Answer (score 0):

Where are you verifying if the `formErrors` is empty? This verification (the if-else) should be inside the function which submits the form.

Also try using:

> if (formErrors.length > 0)

instead of:

> if (formErrors !== {})